# Send a mysqli_query() to an intranet with a remote php-script

Tags: php, android, mysql, vpn

currently, I am programming an Android app that connects to a php-server. On that server are some php-scripts, which send mysqli_queries and receive responses of remote mysql databases.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $db_host = $_POST["dbhost"];
    $db_uid = $_POST["dbusername"];
    $db_pass = $_POST["dbpassword"];
    $db_name = $_POST["dbname"];

    if ($db_host == "" || $db_uid == "" ||  $db_pass == "" || $db_name =="" ) 
        echo "Missing information!";
    else
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_uid, $db_pass, $db_name);
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_error())
            die("Couldn't connect to the database!");
        else
            echo "Connection Successfull";
    }
?>
```

That works without any problems, but now, I need to connect to an intranet first, to get access on a local database.

I thought about a php-script that connects to the intranet (via vpn) and if the connection is established it runs the mysql queries.
After the php-script received the response it disconnects and sends the result back to the Android app. Sadly I've never done that before and Google seems to not know an answer.

I don't want that the whole server connects to the intranet itself, just the scripts are allowed to establish a connection, because other mysqli_queries are executed at the same time.

My question, is that possible?
And if it isn't, is there another solution how to solve my problem?

Thank you pretty much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is that you created a web service on your intranet and you consume it from your android device you can enviyer gives them the get method of utl web service.
For the augulenter securiter your web service you can add a variable that you patage between the web service and the android application.

Comment: I don't have access to the intranet myself. This app are for company owners or workers who want to add data to their enterprise resource planning system.

Comment: With a vpn-client. Or what do you mean? The intranet has no connection to the outside, except for people who want to connect to the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you have to setup a specific port that will communicate outside or an api and secure it via a public key. More exactly you can just forward a port what can work on http from the server in your intranet. Something like http://address:8888 and pull data through an API . That's the most secure way. Please take this answer into account only if you feel that I understood correctly. If now add a comment and I can still give you some ideas.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any access to the intranet.